# How to find the Nth maximum from a sorted matrix of order of mxn

Tags: algorithm

A matrix of integers having n rows and m columns and both row's and column's elements are sorted in non-decreasing order.
What is the best method to find the Nth maximum of the array?
For example if the given matrix is of 4x5

```
1  4  5  7
2  6  8  9
10 14 19 23
12 23 33 60
15 24 35 72
```

find the 3rd maximum from the matrix i.e. 35.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem yourself? Please show some effort.

Comment: My solution came up with brute force and even brute force approach becoming hard to me but I think this problem can have a better solution.

Comment: If we take the last element of the array and traverse to column and row and compare these two element and keep track of a counter.
Will this work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Our goal is to check fewest elements to find the N-th maximum value. So we check elements starting from the right-bottom one in this order: {72}, {35, 60}, {24, 33, 23}, {15, 23, 19, 9}, {12, 14, 8, 7} ..., until we find the N-th maximum.</s>

Because we know any element is greater than or equal to its upper and left elements (if they exist), searching in this order can ensure we find the right answer. But we have to search each subset entirely, because elements inside each one may not be sorted.

The correct solution involves a max-heap. We start from the bottom-right element and add the two adjacent elements to the heap. Each time we extract the max element from the heap and add new adjacent (left, top) elements to the heap. In this way, we actually sort the matrix to find the N-th element.

Comment: After some time I also came up with this approach. with each set we can keep a counter. :)
But couldn't think of making set.
Thank you :)

Comment: I use set because I couldn't find a better denotation... Maybe it's not very accurate, but it works :)

Comment: These subsets of elements are called the minor diagonals, or antidiagonals, of the matrix. Note that when `N` is large, on the order of `n×m`, this still traverses half of the matrix. I don't see a better solution that doesn't assume the elements are unique, though, so +1.

Comment: @vbmaster so how do you exactly find 10th maximum ? By investigating {72},{35,60},{24,33,24},{15,23,19,9} only because they contain 10 elements ? If so then the result is invalid since 10th maximum is 14 which is located outside from those sets.

Comment: @tchrikch I was wrong. Priority queue should be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

See each row of the matrix as a sorted array, and do m-way merge from right to left on each array until we find N-th element. The time complexity will be O(N*logm).

I don't think the answer provided by vbmaster is correct. You can't ensure that the anti-diagonal level is always greater than it's upper-left level. Consider the following example:

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
7 8 9
```

use the order suggested by vbmaster, it would be:
{9},{8,5},{7,4,3},{3,2},{1}
however we can see, the third set {7,4,3} has an element that is greater than the second set (7>5), if you use this order to find the 3rd element, you will get the answer of 5; but the correct answer is 7.